# Generic logger interface raises syntax error

Tags: java, generics, interface, syntax-error

I'm trying to achieve the following API:

```
Logger<Widget> logger = new SimpleLogger<Widget>();

// clazz == Widget.class
Class<?> clazz = logger.getLoggerClass();

Logger<Fizz> fizzLogger = new SimpleLogger<Fizz>();

// clazz now equals Fizz.class
clazz = fizzLogger.getLoggerClass();
```

I have:

```
public interface Logger<T> {
    public T getLoggerClass();

    public void setLoggerClass(T clazz);

    public void logTrace(String trace);
}
```

And then `SimpleLogger`:

```
public class SimpleLogger<T> implements Logger<T> {
    private Class<?> loggerClass;

    @Override
    public T getLoggerClass() {
        return loggerClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void setLoggerClass(T clazz) {
        this.loggerClass = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public void logTrace(String trace) {
        System.out.println("TRACE: " + trace);
    }
}
```

However in `SimpleLogger`, on the following line of code:

```
@Override
public T getLoggerClass() {
    return loggerClass;      <==== this line here
}
```

I am getting the following syntax error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class to T

Why am I getting this and what can I do to keep my desired API and remedy the syntax error? Is there a better way to write this using generics best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring that your class is parameterized by some type `T`, which you say can be any class, and then later you want that class to be a subtype of `Class<?>`.  Those are incompatible.

Either you want `T` to actually *be* a `Class<?>`:

```
public interface Logger<T extends Class<?>> {
  T getLoggerClass();
  void setLoggerClass(T klass);
}
```

Or, alternatively, you want to return *the class of `T`* instead of `T` itself.

```
public interface Logger<T> {
  Class<? extends T> getLoggerClass();
  void setLoggerClass(Class<T> klass);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Pryden (+1) - that's starting to make sense. But I guess I'm still not sure which of those 2 options I want. Can you look at the desired API I have at the beginning of my question and help explain to me which of the 2 options I'm looking for? Basically, if I declare a `SimpleLogger<Widget>`, and then call that logger's `getLoggerClass` method, I want `Widget.class`. Etc for any other class. Thanks again!

Comment: With the first option, you would have to declare `SimpleLogger<Class<Widget>>`, but then the type of the parameter would match the type you return from `getLoggerClass()` (they would both be `T`). It sounds like you want the second option: you want one type in the parameter (`Widget`) and a different type returned by `getLoggerClass()` (`Class<Widget>`, because you want to be able to assign it to a variable of type `Class<?>`).

Comment: Thanks again @Daniel Pryden (again +1) - now that you explain it that way, it does sound like I want option #2. However, how would I declare `SimpleLogger`? Would it be `public class SimpleLogger<T> implements Logger<T>`, or would it be `public class SimpleLogger implements Logger<T>`, or something else? Promise this is the last question! Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: @TicketMonster: if you want to parameterize `SimpleLogger`, then it should be declared as `class SimpleLogger<T> implements Logger<T>`. Alternatively, you could declare something like `class SimpleWidgetLogger implements Logger<Widget>` but then it isn't a parameterized type anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a  type mismatch here because `Class` is not `T`.

If you really need to return `T` in `getLoggerClass()` here's a way:

Declare your `loggerClass` as:

```
private Class<T> loggerClass;
```

Define a `T` :

```
private T t;`
```

Then write a constructor:

```
public SimpleLogger(T t)
{
  super() // You know the constructors of Logger...
  this.t = t;
}
```

So then it gets easy to:

```
@Override
public T getLoggerClass() {
    return t;
}
```